# generar tipos de input apartir de selec javaScrip funciones dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
function init() {
    
    let select = document.createElement('input');

    let option1 = document.createElement('input');
    option1.setAttribute("type", "text");
    option1.setAttribute('value', 'default');
    let option1Texto = document.createTextNode("opcion 1");
    option1.appendChild(option1Texto);
 
    let option2 = document.createElement('input');
    option2.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
option2.setAttribute('value', 'default');
    let option2Texto = document.createTextNode("opcion 2");
    option2.appendChild(option2Texto);
 
    let option3 = document.createElement("option");
    option3.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    option3.setAttribute('value', 'default');
    let option3Texto = document.createTextNode("opcion 3");
    option3.appendChild(option3Texto);
 
    select.appendChild(option1);
    select.appendChild(option2);
    select.appendChild(option3);
 
    document.body.appendChild(select);


}
 
 
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Punto 5</title>
        <script src="Scripts/e33.js"> 
        </script>     
    </head>

    <body> 

        <section>

            <option value="value1">opcion 1</option>
            <option value="value2">opcion 2</option>
            <option value="value3">opcion 3</option>



        </section>


    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]hola necesito su ayuda urgente ,soy nuevo en programacion. y solo consigo codigo muy complicado lo cual no me sirve en este momento

JavaScript y las funciones de DOM `createElement`, `setAttribute` y `appendChild`: Codifique una página HTML con (selec) un combo con las opciones `text`, `radio`, `checkbox`, `area` y un botón
boton--> Generar Input.

Al hacer click en el botón llamar a la función de JavaScript “generarInput()” y
dependiendo que opción del combo este seleccionada agregar dinámicamente a la pagina
el componente seleccionado,talves asignando un id y nombre único para cada componente que se agregue pero no me sale

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado al menos, sinó tu pregunta será cerrada por no seguir lo estipulado en [ask] y [example]. Puedes editar tu pregunta pulsando sobre [edit] en el pie de la misma las veces que sea necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a esto, lo meterias dentro de una funcion y se la asignas a un `<button onClick=funcion></button>`

```
let mi = document.createElement("input");
mi.setAttribute('type', 'text');
mi.setAttribute('value', 'default');
```

con esto podrias generar inputs, tendrias que cambiar el type como ves es muy predecible. Mira bien que es tan sencillo como usar `setAttribute` al principio es raro crear elementos con js pero le vas cogiendo ritmo. Animo

Comment: si gracias por la ayuda